# rxjs finally executed before promise resolves

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, observable, es6-promise

Below is a simplified version of my code. The problem is that the finally block is executed early than I would like. I would like it to execute only when all the other Observables are done.

```
let data1 = 'test1'
let data2 = 'test2'

const input = Rx.Observable.from([data1, data2])
    .finally(() => {
    console.log('end')
  })

let output = input.concatMap((text) => {
  let promise = Promise.resolve(text)
  return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise)
})

output.subscribe((x) => {console.log(x)})
```

Output:

```
end
test1
test2
```

Expected output:

```
test1
test2
end
```

Comment: Why do you expect that output? The `concatMap` is being tacked on _after_ the `finally`

Comment: Sorry, that's how I need it to behave, hence my question. I need an alternative

Comment: Also, removing the async/promise out of the `concatMap` does give the expected output... sort of a strange difference in behavior?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that `Observable.from` emits everything immediately and completes. Then both emissions are buffered inside `concatMap` but the source has already completed so the `finally` block is called.

The easiest thing you can do is just put the `finally` block after `concatMap` because that's when it's really done:

```
const data1 = 'test1';
const data2 = 'test2';

const input = Observable.from([data1, data2]);

const output = input
  .concatMap(text => Promise.resolve(text))
  .finally(() => console.log('end'));

output.subscribe(console.log);
```

See live demo (open console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-hnesmn?file=index.ts

Btw, if you really need `.finally` right after `Observable.from` you can't get the output you want because `.finally` is called when `Observable.from` is disposed (completed or errored), which is independent of the chain that follows. In other words `Observable.from` can't know when the following chain completes. It wouldn't even make sense because the Rx contract dictates that there's always only one `complete` or `error` notification. But if you used eg. `Observable.from().finally().share()` then you could have multiple subscribes and what would decide when the source Observable calls `finally()`? It can complete only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the subscription logic and see whether you get what you are looking for

```
output.subscribe(
   (x) => {console.log(x)},
   error => console.error(error),
   () => console.log('Finally I have really reached the END')
)
```

Comment: That actually won't work for me since I need the client to pass me an observable (input) where the client needs to know when the end was reached. My code takes the input, does some modifications to the observable with concatMap and an asynchronous call before subscribing. I'm actually passing input to an Angular pipe so there is also no way in returning another Subject for example. Hence my ordering of the finally before the maps and subscriptions.

Comment: You know what. I have pasted your code in my environment and I get exactly your expected output, i.e.
`test1

test2

end`

Comment: I added a timeout https://jsfiddle.net/muqbppLg/2/ . How does your environment behave with that?

Comment: You are right. Fool of me.
The point is probably how much control you have on the pipe you are going to pass `input` to. If you can create it, then you may find a strategy to achieve what you want. Otherwise it sounds difficult to me.